# Calculating integral sinx dx using Monte Carlo method?

Tags: montecarlo, integral

> I'm trying to calculate integral -1 to 6 sinx dx, but the following gives result  near -1,14 and the correct solution is -0.41987. Where is the mistake? How to make my code look better and more clear?

```
 float MonteCarlo ( float a , float b, long long int N )  // MonteCarlo(-1,6,200) integral -1 to 6 sinx dx
                                                          //N number of random (x,y)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    float positive = 0; // number of points (x,y): 0<y<sinx 
    float negative = 0; // number of points (x,y): sinx<y<0 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        float x= ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX*(b-a)+a;
        float y= ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX*2 -1 ;
        if( sin(x)>0 && y<sin(x) ) positive++;
        if( sin(x)<0 && y>sin(x) ) negative++;

    }

    positive=fabs(a-b)*2*(positive/ (float) N);//positive area
    negative=fabs(a-b)*2*(negative/ (float) N);//negative area
    return positive-negative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an easier approach for MC-integration: You first have to compute the expectation of your samples (= sum/N) and then multiply it with (b-a). But in this case you need many (> 1e6) samples to get an acurate result.

Try this:

```
// MonteCarlo(-1,6,200) integral -1 to 6 sinx dx                
float MonteCarlo ( float a , float b, long long int N )      
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        x= (float) rand()*(b-a) + a;
        sum = sum + sin(x);
    }

    return sum / N * (b-a);
}
```